# ListView with Custom Cursor Adapter is Empty

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am trying to implement a highscores activity, and i`m trying to use a ListView.
But there is a problem:  **list view shows me only an element what was added by .addHeaderView() method, but the adapter elements seem to be invisible.**
Even though adapter.getCount() returns correct number of elements, they are somehow invisible.

Please help, I'm pulling my hair out here.

My Activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/scores_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My ListView row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
/>
```

My activity code:

```
public class ScoresActivity extends Activity   {
private ScoresAdapter adapter;
private ListView scoresList;
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scores);

    scoresList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.scores_layout);    

    SQLiteDatabase dataBase = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getDataBase();     

    cursor = dataBase.query(ScoresDBHelper.SCORES_TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);

    adapter = new ScoresAdapter(this, cursor, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

    scoresList.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scores_list_row, null));

    scoresList.setAdapter(adapter);

    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(adapter.getCount()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My adapter code:

```
class ScoresAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ScoresAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    textViewName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.scores_list_row, null);
}
```

}

Comment: Don't you get complaints that you don't have a layout_height in the row layout? Try to use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, and see if that works. 

Just two remarks, why a linear layout with one element, and why fill_parent in one place and match_parent in another?

Comment: It seems as you should be able to use SimpleCursorAdapter instead of implementing your own.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau
I have added `android:layout_height ="wrap_content"`, did not helped.  

I have tried SimpleCursorAdapter, but that somehow works the same as that, plus later I will need to format date for every row, so I will need a custom adapter anyway.

I have tried this:
`View head = getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
TextView text1 = (TextView) head.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
text1.setText("TEXT");
scoresList.addHeaderView(head);`
... and this way I can see this element in the ListView

Comment: But after doing this:
` @Override
 public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
  TextView textViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
  textViewName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
 }

 @Override
 public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
  return  inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
 }`
... nothing changed. I cant see this elements.
I have tried this on emulator and on Nexus7.

Comment: Make sure that the name column contains data. Set the text to a fixed string and/or log the contents of the db. Add your table definition to the question as well.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau
I was calling cursor.close(); before onDestroy() method.
That was a fail. =(
But now it seems to work. Thanks for support =)

Comment: Great, it's best to wrap the cursor in a loader but that requires some extra work on db cursors. At least use managed cursor (look at the activity class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling 
    `cursor.close();`
before `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: You can never be sure that onDestroy gets called. Cleanup must be done in onPause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 
    **android:layout_height ="wrap_content"**
in your row layout's TextView.